# trouble with recurrent neural network algorithm for structured data classification

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, classification

**TL;DR**

**I need help understanding some parts of a specific algorithm for structured data classification. I'm also open to suggestions for different algorithms for this purpose.**

Hi all!

I'm currently working on a system involving classification of structured data (I'd prefer not to reveal anything more about it) for which I'm using a simple backpropagation through structure (BPTS) algorithm. I'm planning on modifying the code to make use of a GPU for an additional speed boost later, but at the moment I'm looking for better algorithms than BPTS that I could use.

I recently stumbled on this paper -> [1] and I was amazed by the results. I decided to give it a try, but I have some trouble understanding some parts of the algorithm, as its description is not very clear. I've already emailed some of the authors requesting clarification, but haven't heard from them yet, so, I'd really appreciate any insight you guys may have to offer.

The high-level description of the algorithm can be found in page 787. There, in Step 1, the authors randomize the network weights and also "Propagate the input attributes of each node through the data structure from frontier nodes to root forwardly and, hence, obtain the output of root node". My understanding is that Step 1 is never repeated, since it's the initialization step. The part I quote indicates that a one-time activation also takes place here. But, what item in the training dataset is used for this activation of the network? And is this activation really supposed to happen only once? For example, in the BPTS algorithm I'm using, for each item in the training dataset, a new neural network - whose topology depends on the current item (data structure) - is created on the fly and activated. Then, the error backpropagates, the weights are updated and saved, and the temporary neural network is destroyed.

Another thing that troubles me is Step 3b. There, the authors mention that they update the parameters {A, B, C, D} NT times, using equations (17), (30) and (34). My understanding is that NT denotes the number of items in the training dataset. But equations (17), (30) and (34) already involve ALL items in the training dataset, so, what's the point of solving them (specifically) NT times?

Yet another thing I failed to get is how exactly their algorithm takes into account the (possibly) different structure of each item in the training dataset. I know how this works in BPTS (I described it above), but it's very unclear to me how it works with their algorithm.

Okay, that's all for now. If anyone has any idea of what might be going on with this algorithm, I'd be very interested in hearing it (or rather, reading it). Also, if you are aware of other promising algorithms and / or network architectures (could long short term memory (LSTM) be of use here?) for structured data classification, please don't hesitate to post them.

Thanks in advance for any useful input!

[1] http://www.eie.polyu.edu.hk/~wcsiu/paper_store/Journal/2003/2003_J4-IEEETrans-ChoChiSiu&Tsoi.pdf